# If every proper subsequence is monotonic, is the sequence itself monotonic?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If every proper subsequence of some sequence is monotonic(not necessarily in the same direction),is the sequence itself monotonic?
Intuitively it must be true but sadly can't manage the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:   Consider the subsequence obtained by chopping off the first element.  What does that tell you about the relationship of all of the other elements?

Now consider the subsequence obtained by deleting the third element.   What does that tell you about where the first element is compared to the second?